# SQL - Count variances within in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a bit of a dilemma.

In my DB, I have Box Numbers that contain,

> “13NR0123-0001, 13NR0123-0002….“

and other box numbers that don’t.

> “13NR0456”

The reason for the

> -0001, -0002

is that these boxes has subs in the boxes and the other don’t have subs.

I’m trying to ascertain how many boxes I have in my Database, I have written two scripts for each variance but its not giving me the correct answer.

The below is for report for sub boxes

```
select distinct substring(FD_E77BE253,1,len(FD_E77BE253) - 5) as BoxNumber,
count(FD_84A4EF1A) As Document_Count
from FD_Documents
where deleted = '0'
and FD_9DAADEC8 is not null
and FD_E77BE253 like '%-%'
group by FD_E77BE253
```

The below is for no sub-boxes

```
select distinct (FD_E77BE253) as BoxNumber,
count(FD_84A4EF1A) As Document_Count
from FD_Documents
where deleted = '0'
and FD_9DAADEC8 is not null
and FD_E77BE253 not like '%-%'
group by FD_E77BE253
```

The script with no subs work fine, but the one with sub-boxes does not give me accurate figures.

Is there anyway I can combine both??

Expected output must look like the below 
[image]

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: **Please provide some sample table data and expected output**

Comment: Is a box length always either 8 or 13 characters long? Why not instead use the `WHERE` clauses `LEN(FD_E77BE253) = 8` for non-sub boxes, and `LEN(FD_E77BE253) = 13` for sub boxes?

Comment: Box number varies quiet a lot, I would prefer if it will remove the “-” and everything after it as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why your first query doesn't work is that you're grouping on FD_E77BE253 but the field on your select is a substring of the whole, so basically you're grouping on some other data and projecting a sub portion of it. the count belongs to the whole thing not the substring, that why.

In order to fix that you have to create a temp table containing refined data OR write a common table expression for refined data and use it as the source of your final query.

it goes something like this:

```
;with cte1 as (
select substring(FD_E77BE253,1,len(FD_E77BE253) - 5) as BoxNumber, FD_84A4EF1A As Document_Count
from FD_Documents
where deleted = '0'
and FD_9DAADEC8 is not null
and FD_E77BE253 like '%-%'
),
cte2 as (
select distinct (FD_E77BE253) as BoxNumber, FD_84A4EF1A As Document_Count
from FD_Documents
where deleted = '0'
and FD_9DAADEC8 is not null
and FD_E77BE253 not like '%-%'
)

    select distinct cte1.BoxNumber, count(cte1.Document_Count)
    from cte1
    group by BoxNumber
union 
    select distinct cte2.BoxNumber, count(cte2.Document_Count)
    from cte2
    group by BoxNumber
```

Comment: the above is higher grade for me, still learning SQL. could you advise me on how to go about this?

Comment: gives me the below error   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
Invalid column name 'FD_E77BE253'.  This is the correct column name???

Comment: there was a typo is the query, check it out now.
and please mark my answer as best if helpful :)

Comment: that's the one!!! works great, is there anyway to combine the two scripts?

Comment: lovely, you can create the same for the other category and simply combine the result sets using UNIOIN operator

Comment: not sure about that, but I will give it a bash. Thank you so much

Comment: check again, i've included the other query and the final result. there might be slight typos because i don't have the tables on my machine. but it generally is like that.

Comment: thank you so much, error Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Invalid column name 'FD_84A4EF1A'.

Comment: check again, i should've used the aliases in the final select

Answer (score 0):

Just add '-' and use one query to count:

```
select LEFT(FD_E77BE253 + '-', CHARINDEX('-', FD_E77BE253 + '-') - 1) as BoxNumber,
    count(FD_84A4EF1A) As Document_Count
from FD_Documents
where deleted = '0'
and FD_9DAADEC8 is not null
group by FD_E77BE253
```

Comment: it gives me the below error. Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: Yep, there was the wrong order of parameters in CHARINDEX function, I've corrected my answer